# eww-open-file and eww-mode render differently (emacs)

Tags: html, emacs, emacs24, eww, shr

If I open a file with:

```
M-x eww-open-file RET anyfile.html
```

then it opens in a buffer and looks the same as if I had opened the file then called:

```
M-x shr-render-buffer
```

Now if I open `anyfile.html` then do:

```
M-x eww-mode
```

it looks a bit like `HTML mode` (i.e. its just displaying the 'raw' html markup' but without even any coloured syntax highlighting

whats going on?

Comment: wow two tags created for this question

Comment: I've no idea whether thats acceptable or not? they are just the names of the two emacs libraries relating to the question

Comment: _A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question._

So, for me it's ok

Comment: yes - but clearly there must be a (subjective) cut-off point as to how far you go down the taxonomy before the tags become too niche? Its the position of that threshold that I don't have a feel for

Comment: "Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site." – http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: I hope this talk of tags hasn't put off anyone thinking of answering the question - i'm really keen to get to the bottom of it..

Answer (score 1):

`eww-mode` just changes the major mode and doesn't do rendering/setup. If you want to browse a file with EWW use `eww-open-file`